# sub-attribute of attribute in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes

Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304015/creating-attributes-of-attributes-possible), I was wondering what is the right/common way to implement attribute of an attribute in python. Or I am wrong already with such a thought.  Here are the examples:

**method 1**

It's obvious that it doesn't allow `self.father.height`

```
class household:
    def __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1,height1 ):
        self.address = address
        self.father.name = name0
        self.father.height = height0
        self.mother.name = name1
        self.mother.height = height1

household("198 Ave", "John", 6.4, "Jean",5.2)

output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-09f6784cb40e> in <module>
----> 1 household("198 Ave", "John", 6.4, "Jean",5.2)

<ipython-input-179-9ccb52cdb476> in __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1, height1)
      2     def __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1,height1 ):
      3         self.address = address
----> 4         self.father.name = name0
      5         self.father.height = height0
      6         self.mother.name = name1

AttributeError: 'household' object has no attribute 'father'
```

**method 2**

It works well by using a dictionary without the attribute of an attribute, but I tend to use method 1 although it does not work for some reason.

```
class household:
    def __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1,height1 ):
        self.address = address
        self.father = {"name":name0,"height":height0}
        self.mother = {"name":name1,"height":height1}

household("198 Ave", "John", 6.4, "Jean",5.2)
```

Comment: You can read about Classes and Object Oriented programming in python, will help you in this situations: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: maybe, create a parent class  and pass those object in a list and save the list in  attibute name parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is that you first need to initialise self.father and then use self.father.name.

You should also read more about OOP from the python documentatoion

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can get something close to what you intended using [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```
from collections import namedtuple

class household:
    def __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1, height1 ):
        self.address = address
        Parent = namedtuple('Parent', ['name', 'height'])
        self.father = Parent(name0, height0)
        self.mother = Parent(name1, height1)
```

Example:

```
h = household("198 Ave", "John", 6.4, "Jean",5.2)
print(h.father.name, h.father.height)
```

It gives:

```
John 6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which method is the typical/common way to implement it. But certainly, we can get **method 1** to work. @angadsinghbedi is right, we can initialise `self.father` as an valid object with `type("",(),{})`. For more details about creating an empty object, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476841/10457781)

```
class household:
    def __init__(self, address, name0, height0, name1,height1 ):
        self.address = address
        self.father = type("person", (),{})()
        self.father.name = name0
        self.father.height = height0
        self.mother = type("person", (), {})()
        self.mother.name = name1
        self.mother.height = height1

house0 = household("198 Ave", "John", 6.4, "Jean",5.2)
house0.father.name
# John
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 doesn't work for exactly the reason the error message give you: you cannot create a sub-attribute for an attribute that doesn't exist.  You would have to initialize `self.father` to something with a compatible structure; *then* your could assign to the child attributes.

Assigning the dict is a very good way to accomplish your desired result.

If I were to implement this, I would take the name/height pairs as a list or tuple of entries for later expansion.  Some people have one parent; others have more than two.

```
household("198 Ave", [("John", 6.4), ("Jean",5.2)] )
```

Comment: thank you very much for sharing your knowledge